# How to write mutation in graphql-playgraound for the output

Tags: graphql, graphql-playground

I want to see output in graphql-playground of  mutations which I don't know how to do. Code is below.

```
type Query {  
    """ Gets single referral program"""
    program:Program
    setting(level_id:Int!): Setting
}

type Mutation {
    """Define loyalty program for a club"""
    define_program(input:DefineProgram): Program
    """Club level loyalty program configuration"""
    config_program(input:ProgramConfig): Setting
    get_individual_code(input:Individual): String
    get_group_code(input:Group): String
}

type Program {
    id: String
    name: String
    referral_level_id:Int
    enabled:Boolean
}

input DefineProgram {
    name: String!
    type:ReferralType!
    referral_level_id:Int!
    enabled:Boolean = true
    userid: Int
}

input ProgramConfig {
    program_id: Int!
    level_id:Int!
    type:CodeType!
    expirydays:String!
    validity:Int!
    limit:Int!
    userid:Int
}

input Individual {
    member_id:Int!
    days_to_expire:Int!
    first_name:String!
    last_name:String!
    email:String!
    userid:Int
}

input Group {
    member_id: Int!
    days_to_expire:Int!
    people:Int!
    userid:Int
}

input Filter {
  program_id: Int!
  level_id: Int!
}

type Setting {
    program_id: Int
    program_name:String
    level_id:Int
    tier:String
    type:CodeType
    expirydays:String
    validity:Int
    limit:Int
}

enum CodeType {
    NUMERIC
    ALPHA_NUMERIC
}
enum ReferralType {
    INDIVIDUAL,
    GROUP,
    BOTH
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to write for all mutations to get data in graphql-playground.
Help if anyone can.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL playground will actually give you autocomplete capabilities. It sounds like you're just starting out with consuming GraphQL, though, so I would recommend you start with the learning queries [from graphql.org](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/), and then once you're comfortable there, you should be able to put together queries / mutations for your specific examples.